# Datepicker does not work in ObjectHeader

Tags: javascript, sapui5

[Jsfiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/tinachen/vpw6ev1p/)

I am trying to put a date picker in ObjectHeader, but I find that the calendar icon did not work sometimes. I need to hover to the left of this icon, then click, the calendar page of datepicker will show, otherwise it won't respond.

But the datepicker in panel works fine.

I removed `style="width:100%;"` in `id="__xmlview0--datePicker"`, and the focus area appears works fine. But `style="width:100%;"` is added by default. Is there any elegant way to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change to the following XML. It is working at https://jsfiddle.net/n05fru1s/.

`sap.suite.ui.commons.HeaderContainer` is deprecated, use `sap.m.HeaderContainer` instead. Hope it helps! Thank you.

```
<headerContainer>
    <HeaderContainer id="headerContainer" class="dpContainer">
        <content>
            <!--<Label text="simple DatePicker" labelFor="DP1"/>-->
            <VBox>
                <DatePicker id="datePicker" placeholder="It is working" change="handleChange" />
                <!--class="sapUiNoMargin"/>-->
                <u:CalendarLegend id="legend" />
            </VBox>
        </content>
    </HeaderContainer>
</headerContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks ! This demo works fine! But when I run it in SCP webIDE, it produces an error : ` failed to load 'sap/m/HeaderContainer.js' from ../resources/sap/m/HeaderContainer.js: 404 - Not Found sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.Shell.controller`. Do you have any clue?

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ObjectHeader.html#getHeaderContainer . `headerContainer can either be filled with an sap.m.IconTabBar or a sap.suite.ui.commons.HeaderContainer control.`  It seems that the API has not updated yet?

Comment: Hello Tina, i believe that the documentation is not updated. Regarding the error you mentioned, it seems strange to me. Is it related to UI5 library version?

Comment: Hi, I am using version 1.38.14 based on UI5-detector. And I opened sap-ui-core.js, the version is 2.3.0

Comment: See https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.suite.ui.commons.HeaderContainer.html Deprecated API:
Since version 1.44. This control is deprecated in this library since 1.44 and moved to sap.m library that is also part of openUI5.

Comment: Thx ! Change sap.m version to "1.44.8" by modifying manifest.json. The error msg is gone,  but the content in HeaderContainer still didn't show! I can't find them by `inspect element`, but I saw them in my xml view file(in Network). Feel frustrated...

Comment: Can you make a sample for this issue in JSFiddle otherwise I cannot help? :)

Comment: I find that safari and firefox works fine, it inspires me! And I hard reload my chrome, it works! Stupid me ! Thanks very much for your time.